# Hang ceiling fan grounded box but no ground wire

Tags: electrical, grounding, ceiling-fan

I'm trying to hang a ceiling fan and connect the ground wire from the mounting plate but I don't have any ground wire coming from my box. I have verified that the box itself is grounded though by checking that the voltage between the black wire and the side of the box shows voltage. Where should I connect the ground wire to?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your junction box is grounded by the flexible metal armor of the cable feeding the box. You'll need a 10-32 ground screw similar to the one pictured below. You can screw it into one of the two smaller holes on the back of the box. Fasten the ground from your fan mounting plate to the screw.

[image]

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  Would the individual wires be labeled if it was AC/BX?  That's the reason I thought it was FMC with wires pulled in.  Have a great weekend.

Comment: Ah, you might be right that it is FMC -- feel free to revert my edit then

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using metal conduit instead of cables.  The metal conduit will double in function to also be a ground path.

Can connect the ground wire from the fan to a screw on the box, usually there is a screw or screw hole on the box for ground wire/s.